# jQuery - Pull content from another website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to pull content from another website using only JS/jQuery? For example:

Retrieve the number of questions tagged with `html` on StackOverflow.
The number is located on `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html` in the `div` with the class `summarycount al`.

Comment: Possible, but highly unlikely as the website would need to enable CORS, which very, very few will. In this case you sill be stopped by the Same Origin Policy. If you want to scrape data from third party sites reliably, you'll have to do it server side

Answer (score 0):

Try this to open website inside other website:

```
 <div> 
    <object type="text/html" data="http://validator.w3.org/" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
    </object>
 </div>
```

or

```
<script>
    $("#mydiv")
        .html('<object data="http://your-website-domain"/>');
</script>
```

**if you want to just get value, without displaying:**

```
 $( "#yourElement" ).load( "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html #summarycount al" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/
it might be required to be put it in ajax.